# Switch screen to landscape or portrait but don't lock orientation

Tags: android

I would like to accomplish something like this:

1. User is in portrait orientation
2. User clicks a button and is transferred to landscape orientation
3. Orientation is not locked and if user rotates his phone, he is transferred again to portrait orientation.

What would be the correct way to do this? I am trying to lock the screen with the following command:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

And then immediately calling:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

The problem is that this immediately transfers screen back to portrait mode. Screen just blinks for a half a second.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use in java code:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         // requesting to turn the title OFF
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // making it full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

You can also do in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.main"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
```